# C++/CLI managed code exception

Tags: c++-cli

I made a wrapper for some sdk written in C# using C++/CLI to be used with a c++ program. The managed code project has "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" enabled in Visual Studio and .Net Target Framework set to v4.5.2.

My problem is that I receive the below exception:
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.6.52, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I can't reproduce this all the time on the same machine, more of the time is working well.I also checked for test.dll in running directory and it's there.

Thank you.

Comment: Offhand, sounds like you don't have the right version of .Net installed on those computers.

Comment: I see, but I check the .Net installed version before starting install my application. Thanks for your answer.